# socket.io Using socket.on inside a for loop to execute a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have some code for an online multiplayer game using `socket.io`. At one point, clients send data to the server, to receive and process this data I have a socket.on inside a for loop.

Server:

```
function callBack(hand, upCards) {
    return function() {
      io.to('game_room').emit('log', 'callback');
      players[i].socket.off('swapdone', runSwap);
      players[i].swapped = true;
      io.to('game_room').emit('log', 'call doswap');
      doSwap(i, hand, upCards);
    };
};

for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ){
    players[i].socket.on('swapdone', function(hand, upCards) {
      return callBack(i, hand, upCards);
    });
};
```

`hand` and `upCards` are arrays sent from the client using `socket.emit`

Initially my problem was due to not using a callback function to avoid the closure issue, however now I've added a separate `callBack` function to fix this.

The problem now is that when the client sends the `'swapdone'` signal, the code inside the `callBack` function is not executed. I've tried moving functions around but I always get either the closure-callback problem, or the function doesn't execute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`callBack` takes two parameters, you pass three arguments. `i` should be the first parameter of the function. Additionally you have to properly declare `i`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ){
```

Additionally the inner function in `callBack` is useless, as it does nothing. Just remove that.

---

How I would do that:

```
 function callBack(i) {
  return function(hand, upCards) {
    io.to('game_room').emit('log', 'callback');

    players[i].socket.off('swapdone', runSwap);
    players[i].swapped = true;

    io.to('game_room').emit('log', 'call doswap');

    doSwap(i, hand, upCards);
  };
}

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ){
 players[i].socket.on('swapdone', callBack(i));
}
```

Comment: My bad missing the `i` parameter from the function, that was from trying different things. I tried what you suggested, and I get the error "hand is not defined." I think maybe having a named function as the `socket.on` parameter messes up it receiving the data from the client, but I'm not sure?